# Getting 8 channel Muse data in EEGlab?

Tags: eeg

I am trying to do an experiment, can someone tell me if the following makes sense with an Muse 2 that has 4 electrodes:

1. In the first session I am recording the normal 4 channel data doing some activity with muse headband on the forehead.
2. In the second session, I put the muse headband on the top of my head (somewhere around the regions of T3 to T4) and then record the session.
3. I merge both data 4+4 channels in EEGLab (a Matlab based addon) and try to clean the signal artefacts and analyze the 8 channel data.
   Is it a stupid approach to get an 8 channel information via this hack? My activity for both sessions is nearly identical.

Comment: What are you going to do with the data?

Comment: If both sessions are identical, why not collect these 8 channel data in one common session (to actually ensure your above premise) using 2 Muse-2 sets? Btw [prefrontal cortex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefrontal_cortex) is responsible for executive function of secondary consciousness, REM sleep, activation (A)/modulation (M control emotion). The other limbic areas are likely all capable to communicates their evaluation of the visceral state to the rest of the central nervous system. So in a mediation session to become REM sleep you may actually see large A and small M in the former area.

Comment: The muse device has just 4 channels but I am trying to collect 8 channel data using the same device placed at a different position of the head.